# R: Appending text to a file from multiple processes

Tags: r

I'm trying to append text to a file from multiple processes, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

Test script:

```
logfile <- "testing.txt"
for(i in 1:10) {
    fileConn<-file(description=logfile, open="a", blocking=T)
    writeLines("abcdef", fileConn)
    close(fileConn)
}
```

Then running:

```
Rscript test.r &
Rscript test.r &
Rscript test.r &
Rscript test.r &
Rscript test.r &
Rscript test.r &
Rscript test.r &
Rscript test.r &
Rscript test.r &
Rscript test.r &
```

Produces only 35 lines of "abcdef" (expected 100).

Test script 2:

```
logfile <- "testing.txt"
for(i in 1:10) {
    cat("abcdef", file=logfile, append=TRUE, sep = "\n")
}
```

Produces:

```
bcdef
abcdef
abcdefabcdef
abcdefabcdef
abcdefabcdef
abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef

abcdefabcdeff
bcdefabcdef
abcdef
bcdefabcdefabcdef
abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef
abcdef
```

etc.  How do I get the desired behavior, 100 lines of abcdef from 10 different proceses?

Comment: What do you mean with *from 10 different processes?* ? Could you please specify well.

Comment: If you think about it, each process is trying to write to the same file at the same time, so it's not surprising the output ends up jumbled. You would be better off with each process writing to its own file and then using `cat` from the shell (or something more sophisticated) to join them back up.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I am missing something but as I understand the question you want a text file with 100 lines each one with `abcdef`. It can be achieved with just a:

```
tex <- as.matrix(rep("abcdef", 100))
write(tex, file = "textfile.txt")
```